# Creating a promise from a callback with err, value signature

Tags: javascript, callback, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to convert this simple function into a promise. I thought that resolve would take the place of the callback which returns `function(err, value)`. What am I missing here?

```
var retrieveSet = function(offset){
  var opts = {}
  opts.limit = 100
  if(offset) opts.offset = offset
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    chargebee.subscription
    .list(opts)
    .request(resolve);
  })
}


retrieveSet().then(function(data){
  console.log(data)
}).catch(function(e){
  throw e
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var retrieveSet = function(offset){
  var opts = {}
  opts.limit = 100
  if(offset) opts.offset = offset
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chargebee.subscription
    .list(opts)
    .request(function(err, value){
      if(err) return reject(err)
      return resolve(value)
    })
  })
}
```